# Nested Components with angular 13 library

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular13

I created an Angular 13 components library.
I have a component called `<wg-h2>` which will create an `h2`.
The component `<wg-h2>` is created like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wg-h2',
  template: `
    <h2 [ngStyle]="{ 'color': color }">
      {{text}}
    </h2>`,
  styleUrls: ['./H2.component.css']
})
export class H2Component implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.text)
  }
  @Input()
  text!: string;

  onInit


  @Input()
  color!: string;
}
```

In the browser DOM `<wg-h2>` will be like this:

```
    <wg-h2 _ngcontent-une-c76="" text="text h2" _nghost-une-c64="" ng-reflect-text="text h2">
       <h2 _ngcontent-une-c64="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"> 
         text h2 
       </h2>
    </wg-h2>
```

And will be rendered successfully:

[image]

I have another component called `<wg-card>` that has a `<wg-h2>` in the template.
The component `<wg-card>` is created like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wg-card',
  template: `
  <div class="card text-center {{classShadow}} wg-transition (mouseover)="classShadow='SH-05'" (mouseout)="classShadow='SH-02'" [ngStyle]=" {'width': width}">
    <img class="card-img-top wg-transition" src="{{srcImage}}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <wg-h2 class="card-title wg-transition" text="{{title}}" fontSize="24px" color="var(--color-primary-100)"></wg-h2>
      <wg-body-1 class="card-text"
        text="{{description}}"
        fontSize="20px"
        color="var(--color-grey-60)">
      </wg-body-1>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./card.css'],
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  public classShadow: string = "SH-02";

  @Input() srcImage: string = '../../../../assets/icons3D/rocket.png';
  @Input() title!: string;
  @Input() description!: string;
  @Input() width!: string;
}
```

**The Problem:**

When I build the Angular library with `ng build` and use the card component from `./dist` the `<wg-h2>` component inside `<wg-card>` do not render its content, the browser dom shows this:

```
<wg-card _ngcontent-lqj-c76="" _nghost-lqj-c50="">
  <div _ngcontent-lqj-c50="" class="card text-center wg-transition SH-02" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]">
    <img _ngcontent-lqj-c50="" alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top wg-transition" src="../../../../assets/icons3D/rocket.png">
    <div _ngcontent-lqj-c50="" class="card-body">
      <wg-h2 _ngcontent-lqj-c50="" fontsize="24px" color="var(--color-primary-100)" class="card-title wg-transition">
      </wg-h2>
      <wg-body-1 _ngcontent-lqj-c50="" fontsize="20px" color="var(--color-grey-60)" class="card-text">
      </wg-body-1>
    </div>
  </div>
</wg-card>
```

You can see clearly the `<wg-h2>` does not render its content.
Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: It’s easier to see what is going on if you also post the actual wg-h2 component and template.

Comment: As a guess.. try this in the template: instead of text="{{title}}", use [text]=“title”

Comment: Is the `wg-h2` element imported in the `wg-card` module?

Comment: `<wg-h2>` component with template added

Comment: Maybe your `<wg-card>` has an empty `title` as input. isn't it? (can you render the `{{title}}` inside of it's template to debug it, to make sure the title isn't empty.).

Comment: I think interpolation here is problematic. I’d really recommend using <ng-content> for wg-h2 and use it as <wg-h2>{{title}}</wg-h2> instead of  using the text input.

Comment: Thank you @TsvetanGanev yes, importing the module solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by importing the `<wg-h2>` components module inside the `<wg-card>` module.
Thanks a lot @Tsvetan Ganev